# Come si rende "new outbreak" nel contesto della pandemia di COVID-19?

Tags: translation, word-choice, phrase-request

Nel contesto della pandemia di COVID-19, purtroppo nel mio paese di questo si parla molto ultimamente: in spagnolo si usa il termine "rebrote" (e in catalano "rebrot") per designare le situazioni in cui si trovano
alcune zone nelle quali
c'è di nuovo una crescita significativa del numero di malati, come potete vedere, per esempio, in questo recente [articolo di giornale](https://www.elperiodico.com/es/sociedad/20200706/rebrote-coronavirus-lleida-segria-improvisa-medidas-8028961). In realtà, questo termine proviene dal vocabolario usato per le piante: il verbo "brotar" significa "germogliare", in modo che "brote" è l'azione di germogliare e "rebrote" sarebbe l'azione di germogliare di nuovo.

Per quanto ne so, in inglese, si usa l'espressione ["new outbreak"](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/jun/19/anxiety-in-beijing-as-officials-battle-new-coronavirus-outbreak). Come si può rendere questo concetto in italiano nel contesto che ho descritto?

Comment: Il dizionario di inglese che ho consultato dà *epidemia* come accezione medica di *outbreak*, oppure *esplosione di epidemia*. Quindi siamo alle solite: invece di dire semplicemente *epidemia* si adopera una parola inglese, fa più fino.

Comment: @egreg: Anch'io ho visto "epidemia" come traduzione di "outbreak" sui due dizionari inglese-italiano che si trovano su WordReference. Ma veramente si userebbe "epidemia" o "esplosione di epidemia" nel contesto che ho spiegato nella domanda?

Comment: Di solito si dice “focolaio di epidemia” per casi in cui la diffusione è ancora limitata.

Comment: @egreg: Quindi, l'espressione potrebbe essere "nuovo focolaio"?

Comment: *“per designare le situazioni che si stanno dando in alcune zone in cui c'è di nuovo una crescita del numero di malati.”*  Forse intendi “situazioni che si stanno *creando/sviluppando* in alcune zone”.,,.

Comment: @Hachi: "Si dà la situazione" non si usa in italiano?

Comment: Riguardo outbreak, il significato originale del termine  inglese è “scoppio” e viene  usato spesso in riferimento a malattie o fatti gravi ( una malattia o una guerra ad esempio), “outbreak of cholera“ o “outbreak of a war.” In italiano il termine scoppio è usato in maniera analoga, *scoppio  del colera o è scoppiata una guerra.*

Comment: Hmm... Recrudescenza?

Comment: Va bene, @Hachi, ma io mi riferisco, per esempio, a questo (se ne possono trovare molti esempi in più): https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/jun/19/anxiety-in-beijing-as-officials-battle-new-coronavirus-outbreak.

Comment: “new coronavirus outbreak” io lo tradurrei come “nuovi casi di coronavirus”,  “nuovi focolai di coronavirus” il senso è: *lo scoppio di nuovi casi, nuovi focolai di coronavirus.*

Comment: Riguardo “si dà la situazione”  cosa significa esattamente?

Comment: @Hachi: Che alcune zone del mio paese (e di molte altre parti del mondo) si trovano in questa situazione: il numero di malati di COVID-19 cresce di nuovo di forma significativa.

Comment: “In forma significativa”, comunque la frase “le situazioni che si stanno dando in alcune zone” non ha senso in italiano.

Comment: Ma i mezzi di comunicazione italiani che espressione usano quando danno questo tipo di notizie? "Nuovi focolai"? "Scoppio di nuovi focolai"?

Comment: ***Vicenza, torna dall’estero e scoppia un nuovo focolaio: 5 positivi e 40 in isolamento.*** https://corrieredelveneto.corriere.it/veneto/cronaca/20_luglio_02/vicenza-torna-dall-estero-scoppia-nuovo-focolaio-4-positivi-30-isolamento-61bac424-bc34-11ea-8e0f-bd29d4b494d3.shtml - ***La mappa dei nuovi focolai di Coronavirus in Italia regione per regione*** https://www.fanpage.it/attualita/la-mappa-dei-nuovi-focolai-di-coronavirus-in-italia-regione-per-regione/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In italiano, invece della similitudine con la pianta che germoglia, si adopera la similitudine con il fuoco.

In un focolare si tenevano braci accese per poter avviare il fuoco quando occorreva. Nella mia lingua regionale si adopera il termine “bronsa cuerta” (brace coperta) per indicare una persona all'apparenza mite ma invece potrebbe scatenarsi all'improvviso.

Nel caso di epidemie, un piccolo gruppo di infettati può rapidamente diffondere il contagio se non viene isolato. Così si adopera la variante dotta di *focolare*, cioè [*focolaio*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/focolaio/), che è un termine piuttosto comune [nel gergo medico](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/focolaio_%28Dizionario-di-Medicina%29/).

Si può dire “si è formato un focolaio di infezione” o anche “esploso”, “scoppiato” o simili. Dipende dalla grandezza del focolaio.